# Extend std::vector to move elements from other vector type

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Let's assume I have a non-STL vector type that is compatible with std::vector by an `operator std::vector<T>`. Is it possible to *move* its elements to a std::vector instead of the default copy construction, so that

```
OtherVectorType<SomeClass> f()
{
    OtherVectorType<SomeClass> v;
    v.pushBack(SomeClass());
    v.pushBack(SomeClass());
    v.pushBack(SomeClass());
    return v;
}

std::vector<SomeClass> sv = f();
```

would use SomeClass's move constructor (3 times) when creating the std::vector `sv`?

I imagine something like

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator= (std::vector<T>& self, OtherVectorType<T>&& from)
{
    [...]
}
```

but haven't found any working solution yet.

---

For illustration, this is how the std::vector operator is defined:

```
template<typename T> class OtherVectorType
{
    [...]

    operator std::vector<T>() const
    {
        if (!m_size)
            return std::vector<T>();

        return std::vector<T>(reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_pElements),
                              reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_pElements) + m_size);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a move_iterator in there.

Comment: And you want the C++11 *this reference mechanism so you can overload on whether *this is an lvalue or an rvalue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need support for [rvalue references for `*this`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm).

```
operator std::vector<T>() const &; // copy your own type's data
operator std::vector<T>() &&;      // move it into the std::vector<T>
```

Sadly, support is rare, even GCC 4.8 does not have it. :(

Comment: Very interesting, I was sure C++11 would solve that somehow :) Guess then I'll wait until it's more widely supported.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do (especially if you don't have rvalue-this) is to make use of `make_move_iterator` as demonstrated below:

```
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>

typedef std::unique_ptr<int> SomeClass;
typedef std::deque<SomeClass> OtherVectorType;

OtherVectorType
f()
{
    OtherVectorType v;
    v.push_back(SomeClass(new int (1)));
    v.push_back(SomeClass(new int (2)));
    v.push_back(SomeClass(new int (3)));
    return v;
}

std::vector<SomeClass>
to_vector(OtherVectorType&& o)
{
    return std::vector<SomeClass>(std::make_move_iterator(o.begin()),
                                  std::make_move_iterator(o.end()));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<SomeClass> v = to_vector(f());
}
```